# How to send text and "printenv" in the same line?

Tags: bash, docker

I need to send some environment variable and some text to docker container log but i need to send is as one line.

`echo "SOME_TEXT >> /proc/1/fd/1"`

`printenv VERSION >> /proc/1/fd/1`

How can i do that?
Thank you.

Comment: `printf 'SOME_TEXT%s\n' "${VERSION}" >> /proc/1/fd/1`?

Comment: Or if you REALLY need to execute a command: `printf 'SOME_TEXT%s\n' "$(printenv VERSION)"`